# Gridview Hidden Field - how can I get a hidden field value using JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net

I have Gridview like this:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvPartsSearchResult" runat ="server" CssClass="MRJ_TextGrid"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton 
                    ID="rdButton" 
                    runat="server" 
                    AutoPostBack ="true"            
                    onclick="javascript:CheckOtherIsCheckedByGVIDMore()"/>
                <asp:HiddenField 
                    ID="hdnFileExtension" 
                    runat="server" 
                    Value ='<%#Bind("FILE_EXTENSION")%>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I want to read the hidden field value when the user clicks on the radio button.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

One of the things about ASP.NET that is tough is that the ID's of your controls get mangled,  This can make them tough to work with in JavaScript.

ASP.NET 4 offers a new [ClientIDMode](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/default.aspx#_TOC3_5) which eases this pain but until it is released we are stuck using workarounds.  I [wrote an article](http://togaroga.com/blog/2009/10/asp-net-jquery-and-the-mangled-id/) explaining the pros and cons of some of these workarounds - hopefully that will get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to make your JavaScript more unobtrusive and get rid of your inline event-handler on your radio button:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table.MRJ_TextGrid input:radio').click(function() {
        var hiddenValue = $(this).next().val();
        // continue processing...
    });
});
```